# iOS Swift 4 Restart Navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

My storyboard looks like this:

> Navigation Controller -> StepOne -> StepTwo -> StepThree

`StepOne` has a Segue Show to `StepTwo` etc.

In `StepOne` I open `StepTwo` on Button click like this:

```
 @IBAction func next(_ sender: UIButton) {

     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "oneToTwo", sender: self)

 }
```

In `StepTwo` I open `StepThree` the same way.

Now In my last `StepThree` I want to restart at `StepOne` :

```
@IBAction func end_click(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
}
```

This works fine.

The problem is that all the UI elements are still filled out from the first run. Of course I could clear all values before I navigate in each controller but this doesn't seem to be good practice.

Is there a way to tell `NavigationController` to use new instances of its `ViewController` s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
// this inside end_click
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"StepOneId")
self.navigationController!.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
```

Comment: `let vc = StepOne()` in my case? Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value. This is probably because I have code in StepOne viewDidLoad() that refers to UI elements of that view

Comment: if you create it in IB , load it like edit and set an identifier to it like `StepOneId`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. I set Storyboard ID of `StepOne` to `StepOneID` and tried your code. Now nothing happens when I click my button.

Comment: Do you have a crash or what ? also try `self.navigationController!` instead of `self.navigationController?` what you get ?

Comment: That did the job.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can simply dismiss the root view controller of navigation controller and present it again.